# javascript wait for the new page load in child window

Tags: javascript, oauth

I am doing oAuth using javascript.for this I open a new window with the authorization url,then in this new window user authenticates and the window is loaded with the page having access_token.

Now I want to access this token from the original window.so basically I want to wait until the user has authorised and new page(with access_token) is loaded in the opened window,then access it.How to do this

```
authWin=window.open('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?   response_type=token&client_id=3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp4VNFwdCLxJdMbnQrg44lVcvrLG5Qjp3serQQunkCgdS1bYXMSYDQhiSWazvF_J7oVZ9dBw&redirect_uri=sfdc://success','','width=500,height=300');

//code which is not working
while(true){
    var uri = authWin.document.URL;
    if(uri.indexOf('AuthorizationPage')!=-1){
       alert('now I can get access_token');
       break;
    }
 }
 //I know while(true) locks the system,but please provide alternative for this
```

please help

Comment: what do you mean by token. Is it a client id or anything else. You have to pass token as a parameter to new window , if you want to get it.

Comment: the new window is successfully opened and user is able to authenticate,means oauth is working properly.The only thing I need is to access the new window(authWin),once the oauth dance is finished.so my question is about javascript and not oauth

Comment: you can access new window by 'authWin' as it now become object and contains all the info about open window.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using setInterval()

```
var timerId = setInterval(function () {

            if (typeof(authWin.opener) === 'object') { //if user closed authWin stop awaiting auth
                try {
                    var tokenUri = authWin.location.pathname; //this throwing a error while user not on the same domain(see "same origin policy"), we catch exception and processing like awaiting user back
                    clearInterval(timerId); //when user get back after remote auth on our domain we again have access to authWin properties

                    var token = tokenUri.replace(/\/#access_token=(.+?)&.+/, '$1'); //parsing token from uri
                    authService.saveAuthToken(token);
                    authWin.close();

                    //do something ...
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log('waiting for user back');
                }
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(timerId);
            }

        }, 2000);
```